# Add trailling slashes to all routes in Express

Tags: node.js, express

How can I redirect `/about` to `/about/` and all my other subsequent routes in Express? I heard that its best practice to do so.

**app.js**

```
// Enable strict routing
app.set('strict routing', true);

app.route('/').get(function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
      title: 'Welcome'
    });
});

app.route('/about').get(function(req, res) {
    res.render('about', {
      title: 'About'
    });
});

//etc
```

Answer (score 1):

There is the `connect-slashes` middleware that you can make use of - https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-slashes